# Site vertification equivalent for DFP

Tags: google-dfp

AdSense has this option: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2781214?hl=en which allows you to restrict the display of your Ad content to only your site.

I was wondering if an equivalent exists for DFP small business, and if so where? I can't seem to find anything similar in any of the DFP or API settings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no equivalent of this in DFP SB.

It's hard to find any official documentation explicitly confirming this so no direct link proving this provided